# Use typescript to restrict object keys to string type only

Tags: typescript, object, generics

I would like to create a function called `func` which takes in an argument `arg` which is of type `Record<string, unknown>`.

```
const func = <Arg extends Record<string, unknown>>(arg: Arg) => {
  return arg
}
```

Only keys of type string should be allowed:

```
func({
  'a': 'foo',           // correct
  b: 'foo',             // correct
  ['2']: 'foo',         // correct
  [1]: 'foo',           // incorrect
  5: 'foo',             // incorrect
  [Symbol()]: 'foo'     // incorrect
})
```

How can I edit `func` to restrict any non-string keys in `arg`?

Here is a [typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=3&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAggJwOYwCmAHlIWACYQwBKhoOFG0OAlmHgDQxIDWYIAO5gAfCIAUAQ3wAuGLjwBKNCJgBvAFAwYOQlAQ4wMaXg0BfDRsTJxm7QHJJ9ufbggQ97tu8+YAej8YBl1gKC0YACMXNw8vX3iAoJAcELDtAG17ACZ7AF1o909470Tg+jSYdIBGfJhXQrji-0D2MtDwgFYC2KbfRNbk1PD0gGUATwBbCJAAG3FFWvqPPpbkQfLzRSA).

Comment: `['2']: 'foo'`, `[1]: 'foo'`, and `5: 'foo'` are exactly the same from language level. All (non-symbol) object properties are converted to a string amyway. So `'2'` and `2` are exactly the same at the end. TS *does* distinguish `number` as a possible key type but that's only to account for stuff like array indexes. `arr[2]` fetches the same item as `arr['2']`